# string Date conversion to HH:MM

Tags: excel-formula

i do have a query and i am stuck in excel formula. the case is i have a string date,
eg;

```
"1mos 1w 2d 16h 45m 40s"
"1w 1d 23h 10m 43s"
"3d 16h 13m 10s"
"1y 0mos 3w 0d 23h 57m 24s"
```

i need to convert these dates into HH:MM format

i tried couple of formula in Excel like finding the length and delimiting. but i am getting error coz of the space in between of month, day and week

```
{=MID([Date]],IF( (FIND("w",[Date]])) > 1,1,2), FIND("w",(*Column position")-1)}
```

Could anyone give any idea how to get dates in HH:MM format ?

Comment: do we assume a 30 day month? or a 30.417?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula if you have Excel 365 current channel:

```vb
=LET(splitData,TEXTSPLIT(A2,," "),
REDUCE(0,splitData,LAMBDA(a,v,
        LET(amount,TEXTBEFORE(v,config[Shortcut]),
            shortcut,RIGHT(v,LEN(v)-LEN(amount)),
            days, INDEX(config[days],MATCH(shortcut,config[Shortcut],0)),
               a + (amount * days)))))
```

The formula is in cell `E11` which is formatted with number format `[hh]:mm`

I am using a config table, applying the number of days per shortcut.

`C1:F8` shows the manually calculated result.

- first row of the formula splits the data into single parts.
- The `REDUCE` takes each part,
- retrieves the amount and the days based on the short
- summarizes the days to the final result

[image]

Comment: Hi Ike, really appreciate for the solution, but unfortunately the value i am getting is wrong . For the above mentioned example i am getting 16:45, not sure where it went wrong

Comment: You have to use number format [hh]:mm - square brackets are necessary to show the amount of hours.